# Create PATCH endpoint for list property

Tags: java, rest, api-design

I have the endpoint PATCH /contacts
I want to PATCH my contacts with a tag list, so created a property for that but i don't know how must be the API Call body.
I think { "tags" : ["tag1", "tag2"]} but I don't know how to remove or update a list entry via REST

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [JSON Patch RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) as a guideline. Basically, you'd be sending up a JSON document which contains instructions on how to modify the endpoint. A sample might look something like:

```
   PATCH /my/data HTTP/1.1
   Host: example.org
   Content-Length: 326
   Content-Type: application/json-patch+json
   If-Match: "abc123"

   [
     { "op": "test", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": "foo" },
     { "op": "remove", "path": "/a/b/c" },
     { "op": "add", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": [ "foo", "bar" ] },
     { "op": "replace", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": 42 },
     { "op": "move", "from": "/a/b/c", "path": "/a/b/d" },
     { "op": "copy", "from": "/a/b/d", "path": "/a/b/e" }
   ]
```

Comment: isn't it too verbose? The frontend need to use the endpoint with {key: value} for older properties too, how can i preserve compatibility and not be a mess?